# How to find equivalent resistance with cross resistors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, symmetry, electrical-resistance

When there is a resistor connected in a cross pattern, how do you calculate equivalent resistance? For example in the question shown, my best attempt was to find every path which the current could flow through giving a resistance of 4 ohms. However, does that just mean we ignore the other resistors?

[image]

Comment: Hint: By symmetry no current crosses the $AB$ line, i.e. the circuit can be cut in two.

Comment: You can fold it along the line AB and replace the overlapping resistors with R/2 .. since there are two equivalent paths for current to flow, each overlapping resistor will get halved. I think Qmechanic is saying the same thing.